# how can i change fields from text to option box?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want to change the type of car_engine from text to option but i do not even understand what this code means and in which language i shall write my modification.

i have tried no thing because i had no idea where should i start.

```
public static function front_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields[] = [
        'forms'             => ['car', ],
        'type'              => 'fieldset',
        'id'                => 'car',
        'legend'            => esc_html__( 'Car', 'listing-manager' ),
        'collapsible'       => true,
        'fields'            => [
            [
                'id'        => LISTING_MANAGER_LISTING_PREFIX . 'car_engine',
                'type'      => 'text',
                'label'     => esc_html__( 'Engine', 'listing-manager' ),
                'required'  => false,
            ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this way (untested):

```
public static function front_fields( $fields ) {
                        $fields[] = [
                            'forms'             => ['car', ],
                            'type'              => 'fieldset',
                            'id'                => 'car',
                            'legend'            => esc_html__( 'Car', 'listing-manager' ),
                            'collapsible'       => true,
                            'fields'            => [
                                [
                                    'id'        => LISTING_MANAGER_LISTING_PREFIX . 'car_engine',
                                    'type'      => 'select',
                                    'label'     => esc_html__( 'Engine', 'listing-manager' ),
                                    'required'  => false,
                                    'options' =>   [ //options may be values
                                         'alabama' => 'Alabama',
                                         'alaska'  => 'Alaska'
                                     ],
                                    'placeholder' => '',
                                ],
                             ]
                    );
```